# Can't create files and directories

Tags: files, directory, external-hdd

I am using Mint. Everything was fine until three days ago. I wanted to create a file but I discover that my external HDD has read-only mode (file system is NTFS). I didn't change anything before but OK, maybe it was just a little error. I fix it pretty quickly. But even now I can't create any file or directory, also I can't edit any existing file (actuality I can but file get error and I get senseless combination of random symbols and "\00\00\"). When I try to create text file or directory I get next error:

```
root@mint:/media/mint/A47A802C7A7FF97E# cat > text.txt
bash: text.txt: No such file or directory
root@mint:/media/mint/A47A802C7A7FF97E# mkdir -p directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘directory’: No such file or directory
```

Running with sudo also doesn't help. It worked thousand times before but not now. Is my drive gone or I do something wrong? I found a lot of different solutions but there is no my one. I hope there is really simple way to fix that.

UPD: I am sure that drive is really rw. 
But I run `ntfsfix --no-action /dev/sdX` and get

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
No change made
```

Also `sudo fsck /dev/sdX` detected a difference between original boot sector and its backup.

Comment: *"I discover that my external HDD has read-only mode. I didn't change anything before but OK, maybe it was just a little error."*  "Little errors" don't happen like that.  Probably the system detected fs corruption and automounted it read-only.  *"I fix it pretty quickly."*  How? Which commands did you run?

Comment: Try posting the output of `cat /proc/mounts/`. Also do a `stat /media/mint/A47A802C7A7FF97E`. This path may not exist(and still be the working directory of the shell) as these folders usually are created dynamically.

Comment: @dr01 I run `sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/mint/A47A802C7A7FF97E` so I should be able to create file and directories, isn't it?

Comment: @rudib Path really exist. Moreover, last modified is dated September, 30th - right before the day my problem had begin.

Comment: `sudo mount -o remount,rw` will attempt to mount as `rw`, but if there is a problem, it may fall back to `ro`. That's why `cat /proc/mounts/` might give us a hint.

Comment: In addition to that `mounts` will tell us what filesystem you are using so you could then run a file system check.

Comment: @rudib File system is NTFS and there's no errors and it's still shown as rw. I tried to check a lot of times but nothing's change.

Comment: Try `sudo fsck /dev/sdX`. `sdX` corresponds to the device you mounted. Also you can try `ntfsfix --no-action /dev/sdX`. And post those outputs. The latter requires `ntfs-3g` to be installed (which is also required for mounting `ntfs` in `rw`, so it should already be installed).

Comment: @rudib Oh, I run `ntfsfix --no-action /dev/sdX` and get `NTFS signature is missing. Unrecoverable error. Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk. No change made`. Also `sudo fsck /dev/sdX` detected a difference between original boot sector and its backup.

Comment: Please update your question so that it makes sense without reading all the comments. I.e.: include the test results and current status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Ensure that there is no hardware problem:**
  Check this with `smartctl -a /dev/sdX`. (You may have to installl `smartctl` first). Also check the output of `dmesg | tail`.
- **Warning, read carefully:**
  Note that all that actions may/will change the data on the disk and might cause more damage. If possible, you should make a raw **backup** (with `ddrescue` for example) of the disk to an unrelated storage medium before changing anything. Proceed at your own risk.
- **Try to fix the filesystem:**
  You can try to run `ntfsfix /dev/sdX`.
  You can also use the tool `testdisk` to attempt a fix. It has more options and is interactive.